# Prove: Euclidean and Cofinite topologies on $\mathbb{R}$ are not Homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}$ denote the real numbers with the standard topology and $\mathbb{R}_f$ denote the real numbers with the cofinite topology.

1. Explicitly show that the identity map between these two spaces is not a homeomorphism.
2. How do we know there is no homeomorphism between them? (think about a property that must get preserved under a homeomorphism)

Since I am a new with topology. Please give me some advice.
Thanks

Comment: Well, what properties does a map need to satisfy to be a homeomorphism?

Comment: If $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are two topologies on $X$, the definition yields that the identity map $id_X:(X,\tau_1)\to (X,\tau_2)$ is a homeomorphism if and only if $\tau_1=\tau_2$.

Comment: For the second part: how many infinite closed sets are there are in $R$ and in $R_f$?

Comment: For the second part you could show that $\Bbb R_f$ is compact, while $\Bbb R$ is not.